# Can I specify multiple constraints on a single generic type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, mvvm

Using an MVVM design pattern example; say I have a Model and a ViewModel:

```
public class UserAccountModel
{
}

public class ViewModel<TModel>
{
    public TModel Model { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel(TModel model)
    {
        this.Model = model;
    }
}

ViewModel<UserAccountModel> = new ViewModel(new UserAccountModel());
```

But now I need to add some functionality to listen to models so that when they change, I can update the view accordingly:

```
public class UserAccountModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Implementation for INotifyPropertyChanged
}

public class ViewModel<TModel> where TModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TModel Model { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel(TModel model)
    {
        this.Model = model;
    }
}

ViewModel<UserAccountModel> = new ViewModel(new UserAccountModel());
```

This works for models where you want to determine that a property has changed, but now I want to also create collection models, which implement a different interface:

```
public class UserAccountCollectionModel : ObservableCollection<UserAccount>
{
}

public ViewModel<UserAccountCollectionModel> vm = new ViewModel<UserAccountCollectionModel>(new UserAccountCollectionModel());
```

This errors because `UserAccountCollectionModel` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` - instead it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`

So what I want is:

```
public class ViewModel<TModel> where TModel : INotifyPropertyChanged (or) INotifyCollectionChanged
{
}
```

AFAIK there is no way in C# to do this, so my workaround is:

```
public interface IModel
{
}

public class PropertyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IModel
{
}

public class CollectionModel : ObservableCollection<PropertyModel>, IModel
{
}

public class ViewModel<TModel> where TModel : IModel
{
}
```

This sticks out like a sore thumb to me! I don't think the implementation is at all elegant, given using an empty interface to use for generic constraint.

How should I tackle this in terms of creating an elegant solution?

Comment: One question. In what way you think that `ViewModel<TModel>` is going to be helpful for you? How'll you use it? Remember inheritance is for polymorphism. Not just to reuse single field or property.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - ViewModel<TModel> hooks together the model and the view using a set of data bindings and business logic. For a simple application - say just binding a data entry form to a basic model, you could just create an instance of ViewModel<TModel> and data bind the model to the data entry form using standard bindings. For a more complex application you would be able to override ViewModel<TModel> to add custom functionality, and you could also implement custom bindings.

Comment: I don't see any win situation in that design either. what would be the implementation of ViewModel<TModel>?

Comment: My question is does that `Model` property needs to be there in `ViewModel<TModel>` ? If so, does that needs to be generic? If so, how does that helps really? Btw `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` so I don't understand why this question in first place? I mean `ViewModel<UserAccountCollectionModel> vm = new ViewModel<UserAccountCollectionModel>(new UserAccountCollectionModel());` should compile, in fact it compiles for me.

Comment: i mean you could implement both interfaces by the viewmodel. check in the constructor whether T is INotifyPropertyChanged and hook in to the event else ignore it and the same thing for INotifyCollectionChanged but i don't see any sense doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you have is to relax the constraints on the `ViewModel<TModel>` class, but make the constructor private and then create two strongly-typed static factory methods that perform the constraint for you.

Like this:

```
public class ViewModel<TModel>
{
    public TModel Model { get; private set; }

    public static ViewModel<T> CreateFromObject<T>(T model)
        where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        return new ViewModel<T>(model);
    }

    public static ViewModel<T> CreateFromCollection<T>(T model)
        where T : INotifyCollectionChanged
    {
        return new ViewModel<T>(model);
    }

    private ViewModel(TModel model)
    {
        this.Model = model;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how you intend to use your `ViewModel<T>` class, it's impossible to provide suggestions for the correct way to implement it. But it is at least possible to comment on the C# aspects…

As far as the constraints go, allowing multiple constraints that are *optional* (i.e. the class could implement either/or) wouldn't make any sense at all. The sole purpose of a constraint in a generic type is to provide a compile-time restriction on the type that allows the code in the generic type to do things with that type.

E.g. if you require `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then in your generic type, you can subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event on the object so-constrained (i.e. any instance of the type parameter's type).

But if the generic type parameter is allowed to simply implement either that interface *or* some other interface, then what can you do with it in your generic type? Nothing at all, except what you could do with it were it completely unconstrained. After all, the "or" constraint basically says either constraint could be omitted, and if that's the case, then there's no guarantee that e.g. a `PropertyChanged` event would be present.

Absent any other information, I would say that the best approach here is to have two different *view model* types. I.e. similar to your proposed workaround, except that you get rid of `IModel`, and `ViewModel<T>`, and have only `PropertyModel<T>` and `CollectionModel<T>`. After all, it's not likely that the two would overlap in any meaningful way anyway.

Comment: +1 I very much doubt that they would indeed overlap in any way! INotifyProp = Model where its properties are changing, INotifyCol = colleciton. Usuall the INotifyCol contains a list of INotifyProp. I Just cant think of any scenario you would want both. Especially considering its 2 compeltely different Events! CollectionChanged vs PropertyChanged